# jGRASP c++ setup issue cannot find -lfreeglut

Tags: c++, jgrasp

I'm trying to setup c++ on jGRASP. I know that java programs run fine. The error I'm getting is:

```
----jGRASP exec: g++ -g -o Project Simulator.exe Project Simulator.cpp -lglu32 -lfreeglut -lopengl32
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lfreeglut
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

----jGRASP wedge2: exit code for process is 1.
----jGRASP: operation complete.
```

Am I missing an installation? Do I need to change paths somewhere?

Comment: Found a solution. Went to SETTINGS > COMPILER SETTINGS > WORKSPACE > and chose g++ -generic. Now it works just fine.

Comment: Would you add the solution in the answer box below? Comments are regarded as ephemeral here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The compiler should be g++ -generic

Done through SETTINGS > COMPILER SETTINGS > WORKSPACE under the c++ language.

Answer (score -1):

Just copy files from `freeglut\lib\x64\` to `CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\`.

Hope to help you!

Comment: Hacky workaround, do not use.